# ajax-content not displayed in soapUI using REST

Tags: ajax, soapui

I'm not entirely sure I am asking the question correctly but here goes.

I am trying to view customer data via the REST service. I've gotten the login and and can view the servlet(Response as HTML), atleast i thought it was the servlet, i just realized its just the path to the servlet/start.
I think what I am seeing is just the hardcoded HTML messages that get viewed depending on customer data. Viewing as JSON doesn't work either i get "The content you are trying to view cannot be viewed as JSON"

I'm sorry I don't know enough to ask this properly

Comment: If you select the XML tab in the Response view, what do you see? What about the "Raw" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a n00b mistake. I didnt call the action prior to loading the page so there was no data to ever load.